# Why is 'pt' printed when multiplying two point-based dimensions?

Tags: arithmetic

In this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\dimen1=10pt
\multiply\dimen1 by 20pt
\rule{\dimen1}{10pt}

\end{document}
```

I multiply `10pt` with `20pt`, expecting a value of `200pt` (which is also the case as shown by the resulting rule).

However, there is also the text `pt` being printed as a result of invoking `multiply` with these inputs. Why? And how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Multiplying two dimensions would give an area, except TeX doesn't store areas so it uses just an integer and typesets the `pt`

Comment: Hm, so I need to remove the 'pt' from the dimension before multiplying, then?

Comment: Yes, removing `pt` from `20pt` would make sense and be mathematically correct since you want to *scale* `\dimen1` by some factor and use it as the *width* argument of `\rule` which is still a length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TeXbook Chapter 24 states

> `\multiply`<numeric variable><optional `by`><number>

which means that TeX will scan your input

```
\multiply\dimen1 by 20pt
```

up to the `p` of `pt`, since `p` is not a number and will start typesetting.